# Java button eventhandeling

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, event-handling

I have this assignment to make a game called "Guess the number". The user guess a number between 1 and 1000, click "OK" and recieve a message that says if it was correct, too high or too low. My problem is the eventhandling. When I push "OK", it the program crashes. What am I doing wrong?

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GjettTalletSpill extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

Button ok;
Label text;
Label message;
TextField TF;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);


}// Main.

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Gjett tallet spill");

    ok = new Button("OK");
    ok.setOnAction(this);
    ok.setPrefSize(100,20);
    text = new Label("Guess a number between 1 and 1000: ");
    TF = new TextField();
    message = new Label("");

    GridPane gp = new GridPane();

    gp.add(text,1,1);
    gp.add(TF,3,1);
    gp.add(message,2,2);
    gp.add(ok,2,3);

    Scene scene = new Scene(gp,600,150);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}


@Override 
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

    int uGuessed;
    int theNumber;

    tallet = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 1000); 
    uGuessed = Integer.parseInt(TF.getText());

    while (uGuessed != theNumber){

        if (uGuessed<theNumber){
            message.setText("The number was too low. Try again!");
        } else {
            message.setText("The number was too high. Try again!");

        }// if/else.
    }// while.

    message.setText("Congratulations! You guessed the roght number! :D");
}// ActionEvent.

}// Class.
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?, please post that too

Comment: What is `tallet`? Also that while loop doesn't make sense at all... You're never changing any value in the condition inside the loop body.

Comment: No exception appears. It just freezes..

Comment: It seems more likely that your program gets into an endless loop and freezes, than that it actually crashes. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: "Tallet" is theNumber. I just translated it to english and forgot that one. Very good point fabian!

Comment: Yes I do! Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course your program freezes. When you press the button, you program calls the handle-function and will never return (unless you entered correct number on first try). So your program gets stuck handling the event and e. g. won't call repaint-method any more.

Just remove the while-loop. Remember, your handle-method will be called each time you press the ok-button. So don't generate your random number in the handle-method. Move

```
private int theNumber;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        theNumber = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
```

on top of your start-method to generate a random number once you start your application.

And replace your Action handler so it will only check the number once, update the message label and then return.

```
@Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        int uGuessed;
        uGuessed = Integer.parseInt(TF.getText());

        if (uGuessed < theNumber) {
            message.setText("The number was too low. Try again!");
        } else if (uGuessed > theNumber) {
            message.setText("The number was too high. Try again!");
        } else {
            message.setText("Congratulations! You guessed the roght number! :D");
        } // ActionEvent.
    }
```

and your program should work :).